# Can React's forceUpdate method theoretically cause a more prompt update than setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

My rationale in thinking so is that `setState()` calls can be batched, which I think implies some delay, however small. Can calling `forceUpdate()` theoretically result in a faster (lower latency) update of the component?